# Why does as.ts create new values for the date variable?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I want to create a Time-Series with as.ts.
The Problem is that after using the function as.ts(), the date variable has different values.

Here you can see the difference of the date variable before and after using as.ts()-function:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc4np.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKMnY.png

````
sapply(Oct_Apr, class)
#character to date 
Oct_Apr$date <- lubridate::ymd(Oct_Apr$date)
#Klassen überprüfen 
sapply(Oct_Apr, class)

Oct_Apr %>% as_tsibble(index = "date")
#################################################################
#Trainings and Test-Set 
#Trainings-Set (Okt. 2019 - März 2020)
Oct_Mar <- Oct_Apr %>% slice(01:183)

#Test-Set (Apr. 2020)
Apr <- Oct_Apr %>% slice(184:213)
#################################################################
#################################################################

Oct_Mar <- as.ts(Oct_Mar)
Apr <- as.ts(Apr)```

#################################################################

Subset-data: 
structure(list(date = structure(c(18170, 18171, 18172, 18173, 
18174, 18175, 18176, 18177, 18178, 18179, 18180, 18181, 18182, 
18183, 18184, 18185, 18186, 18187, 18188, 18189, 18190, 18191, 
18192, 18193, 18194, 18195, 18196, 18197, 18198, 18199, 18200, 
18201, 18202, 18203, 18204, 18205, 18206, 18207, 18208, 18209, 
18210, 18211, 18212, 18213, 18214, 18215, 18216, 18217, 18218, 
18219, 18220, 18221, 18222, 18223, 18224, 18225, 18226, 18227, 
18228, 18229, 18230, 18231, 18232, 18233, 18234, 18235, 18236, 
18237, 18238, 18239, 18240, 18241, 18242, 18243, 18244, 18245, 
18246, 18247, 18248, 18249, 18250, 18251, 18252, 18253, 18254, 
18255, 18256, 18257, 18258, 18259, 18260, 18261, 18262, 18263, 
18264, 18265, 18266, 18267, 18268, 18269, 18270, 18271, 18272, 
18273, 18274, 18275, 18276, 18277, 18278, 18279, 18280, 18281, 
18282, 18283, 18284, 18285, 18286, 18287, 18288, 18289, 18290, 
18291, 18292, 18293, 18294, 18295, 18296, 18297, 18298, 18299, 
18300, 18301, 18302, 18303, 18304, 18305, 18306, 18307, 18308, 
18309, 18310, 18311, 18312, 18313, 18314, 18315, 18316, 18317, 
18318, 18319, 18320, 18321, 18322, 18323, 18324, 18325, 18326, 
18327, 18328, 18329, 18330, 18331, 18332, 18333, 18334, 18335, 
18336, 18337, 18338, 18339, 18340, 18341, 18342, 18343, 18344, 
18345, 18346, 18347, 18348, 18349, 18350, 18351, 18352, 18353, 
18354, 18355, 18356, 18357, 18358, 18359, 18360, 18361, 18362, 
18363, 18364, 18365, 18366, 18367, 18368, 18369, 18370, 18371, 
18372, 18373, 18374, 18375, 18376, 18377, 18378, 18379, 18380, 
18381, 18382), class = "Date"), price_view = c(35.79, 180.16, 
437.57, 10.3, 74.26, 79.8, 89.84, 121.24, 461.95, 142.06, 241.71, 
52, 43.24, 41.16, 167.05, 764.06, 91.64, 189.82, 38.59, 152.64, 
86.23, 321.33, 411.83, 256.88, 352.39, 76.32, 360.11, 123.53, 
43.41, 149.38, 14.16, 489.07, 1661.74, 1253.07, 25.71, 154.42, 
990.89, 1645.93, 144.12, 84.43, 240.25, 148.18, 41.13, 262.56, 
168.78, 860.85, 239.31, 372.98, 165.64, 134.32, 20.7, 43.73, 
765.76, 51.48, 599.49, 893.79, 155.29, 334.37, 46.82, 1814.72, 
196.27, 1302.48, 40.16, 1161.68, 381.48, 184.48, 48.91, 221.11, 
434.73, 149.27, 77.22, 882.49, 106.05, 669.23, 282.86, 179.67, 
12.97, 460.24, 38.59, 278.26, 243.76, 1904.79, 84.93, 32.18, 
25.71, 496.54, 29.6, 1466.83, 164.33, 234.76, 19.95, 308.37, 
1130.02, 7.47, 79.8, 65.9, 746.45, 1347.78, 1270.82, 69.42, 231.41, 
195.6, 715.33, 208.47, 720.46, 414.68, 24.45, 217.82, 434.45, 
483.92, 1500.42, 318.15, 339.29, 267.45, 133.85, 9.03, 11.81, 
280.57, 916.74, 58.51, 339.78, 33.98, 263.58, 19.31, 239.88, 
489.07, 84.92, 344.9, 95.24, 99.1, 142.58, 480.58, 104.74, 14.83, 
252, 1039.41, 28.3, 328.97, 341.55, 278.26, 43.73, 91.35, 102.32, 
131.25, 155.15, 77.74, 14.67, 132.63, 1185.36, 291.13, 1106.59, 
849.42, 117.63, 171.32, 167.31, 252.23, 248.14, 111.15, 257.15, 
27.62, 169.86, 101.89, 282.89, 298.57, 86.49, 196.32, 1415.45, 
898.35, 334.6, 17.99, 13.62, 566.27, 60.41, 36.34, 62.04, 308.81, 
32.95, 127.44, 836.57, 221.34, 360.34, 159.31, 20.57, 230.38, 
563.72, 103.71, 509.67, 125.87, 80.27, 37.58, 14.13, 527.14, 
5.15, 567.3, 2316.4, 21.85, 141.06, 25.71, 62.16, 328.68, 15.44, 
156.99, 15.42, 54.03, 514.56, 561.63, 97.56, 46.31, 41.16, 32.15, 
60.17, 809.26, 1026.26), view = c(1206151L, 1152770L, 1087372L, 
1344804L, 1270060L, 1262993L, 1159265L, 1323522L, 1301376L, 1240347L, 
1445162L, 1432321L, 1583572L, 1376274L, 1462409L, 1443323L, 1337174L, 
1413405L, 1382403L, 1443838L, 1342668L, 1353053L, 1318395L, 1252747L, 
1369922L, 1288939L, 1330209L, 1220710L, 1187883L, 1169955L, 1207854L, 
1402754L, 1513400L, 1524803L, 1743304L, 1670637L, 1644359L, 1748812L, 
1789808L, 1783142L, 1845552L, 1907417L, 1892753L, 1920411L, 2864410L, 
5691766L, 5986292L, 5759703L, 1905351L, 1627672L, 1598554L, 1573101L, 
1471242L, 1474138L, 1500022L, 1496128L, 1557252L, 1547199L, 1560191L, 
1727852L, 1644405L, 1706901L, 1629904L, 1547658L, 1468085L, 1540157L, 
1652208L, 1725106L, 1724452L, 1627222L, 1651328L, 1605421L, 1650612L, 
1634861L, 1760750L, 2167056L, 2875847L, 2780816L, 2665285L, 2528244L, 
2387520L, 2340327L, 2471739L, 2372930L, 2326654L, 2322753L, 2240514L, 
2058141L, 2089081L, 2474226L, 2294820L, 1603749L, 1427733L, 1700904L, 
1765457L, 1754424L, 1738774L, 1696188L, 1701769L, 1585870L, 1556542L, 
1557542L, 1618230L, 1645866L, 1627433L, 1612956L, 1555416L, 1773179L, 
1826768L, 2021676L, 2104199L, 1801073L, 1733142L, 1593991L, 1645225L, 
1557626L, 1637470L, 1721003L, 1545472L, 1594688L, 1565742L, 1651606L, 
1999670L, 2217825L, 1985751L, 1680034L, 1608904L, 1620473L, 1628906L, 
1726835L, 1589058L, 1714745L, 1751044L, 1896265L, 2429526L, 2268487L, 
1935249L, 1916034L, 2239698L, 1916650L, 1981570L, 1948648L, 1987134L, 
1749514L, 1822349L, 1830307L, 1748590L, 1734610L, 1798308L, 162557L, 
1000204L, 1257475L, 1770064L, 2416707L, 2477258L, 2487470L, 2457500L, 
2210539L, 2377633L, 2026050L, 2301337L, 2218894L, 2012789L, 1700619L, 
1481115L, 1562027L, 1560348L, 1338829L, 1244973L, 1142989L, 1260747L, 
1316975L, 1387394L, 1319559L, 1440470L, 1451015L, 1439649L, 1390411L, 
1336076L, 1369834L, 1255626L, 1244163L, 1283731L, 1461785L, 1448716L, 
1476317L, 1437668L, 1486293L, 1436223L, 1452446L, 1659354L, 1739377L, 
1871914L, 1970269L, 1956840L, 2068666L, 1946201L, 2340731L, 2511860L, 
2471888L, 2415311L, 2149298L, 2274084L, 2299902L, 2354228L, 2406987L, 
2503970L, 2600158L, 2592352L, 2402199L, 2487428L, 2542154L, 2526912L
), price_cart = c(29.51, 1415.48, 99.86, 358.57, 617.51, 1052.79, 
1747.79, 190.56, 128.28, 252.38, 250.91, 720.48, 33.42, 643, 
191.77, 460.11, 408.5, 789.9, 577.94, 49.36, 380.7, 19.56, 994.86, 
756.71, 223.66, 437.33, 1684.28, 366.16, 968.34, 1683.07, 550.77, 
503.09, 29.09, 179.67, 210.62, 22.66, 131.66, 68.96, 360.06, 
494.22, 1023.62, 1569.92, 28.29, 694.97, 127.05, 37.85, 282.89, 
178.9, 913.28, 1022.42, 424.7, 573.7, 1029.34, 30.12, 20.82, 
17.99, 107.53, 41.19, 85.82, 1002.55, 140.98, 167.03, 231.67, 
25.71, 205.64, 30.81, 51.22, 65.9, 7.08, 308.63, 227.79, 16.22, 
7.89, 62.52, 48.88, 586.63, 602.07, 1312.26, 128.32, 179.9, 849.42, 
100.9, 1284.2, 12.84, 128.42, 59.18, 176.99, 38.02, 48.88, 694.54, 
262.3, 1402.84, 1453.18, 3.84, 453.01, 76.93, 7.04, 865.93, 865.4, 
40.75, 1423.07, 1534.66, 679.27, 11.25, 102.63, 436.3, 853.93, 
694.97, 850.47, 477.49, 1234.97, 10.27, 23.94, 643.23, 89.84, 
290.34, 320.99, 6.44, 140.28, 188.89, 56.88, 1326.31, 194.34, 
140.28, 771.96, 140.03, 20.21, 1464.39, 59.18, 57.92, 1156.81, 
50.43, 300.12, 38.1, 832.71, 57.91, 174.5, 100.36, 248.14, 109.34, 
100.7, 242.7, 266.67, 592.01, 242.18, 22.66, 566.04, 38.61, 812.06, 
123.92, 168.6, 172.03, 49.91, 16.73, 108.04, 347.47, 97.79, 111.15, 
514.79, 126.1, 178.87, 870.03, 529.31, 43.5, 2110.48, 771.94, 
15.32, 105.25, 7.14, 312.67, 61.75, 165.51, 48.37, 643.49, 303.48, 
35.78, 154.42, 209.71, 76.69, 25.46, 1415.45, 123.53, 602.31, 
117.12, 334.35, 455.3, 643.26, 101.16, 245.82, 280.74, 143.89, 
114.67, 12.84, 31.89, 32.69, 203.35, 66.9, 208.24, 57.92, 14.32, 
400.5, 146.46, 827.35, 30.86, 143.89, 47.29, 426.01, 30.07, 36.28, 
108.09, 81.06, 301.91, 434.73), cart = c(16658L, 17268L, 19323L, 
43826L, 35493L, 32145L, 18052L, 18442L, 18432L, 18997L, 21450L, 
20691L, 24833L, 44821L, 49513L, 45272L, 40368L, 40127L, 39455L, 
40533L, 36675L, 36945L, 36407L, 35721L, 36800L, 34776L, 34256L, 
17838L, 17455L, 16996L, 16798L, 18911L, 19350L, 20211L, 21960L, 
19231L, 19670L, 19446L, 77319L, 70093L, 71585L, 75135L, 69669L, 
71613L, 170183L, 481862L, 405584L, 426261L, 83117L, 72450L, 72311L, 
75530L, 70171L, 64801L, 68099L, 71405L, 71622L, 71324L, 71504L, 
92345L, 81760L, 84473L, 80869L, 70192L, 66718L, 71048L, 83618L, 
84231L, 80773L, 80675L, 81420L, 78947L, 80162L, 82360L, 86689L, 
109721L, 183764L, 155406L, 146906L, 137487L, 127900L, 124577L, 
127381L, 126700L, 124797L, 127554L, 123966L, 120940L, 127769L, 
148663L, 148608L, 119062L, 57614L, 71342L, 95608L, 80629L, 78782L, 
79099L, 77396L, 74671L, 72772L, 74827L, 72221L, 73406L, 72999L, 
71182L, 70235L, 79414L, 104791L, 103481L, 102597L, 94354L, 90666L, 
83642L, 83223L, 73075L, 73582L, 73849L, 70067L, 71600L, 72179L, 
130757L, 208231L, 169156L, 137970L, 116560L, 104701L, 102836L, 
101145L, 101605L, 90864L, 92635L, 95114L, 100283L, 158447L, 131720L, 
118661L, 126405L, 132399L, 98277L, 96270L, 95284L, 96886L, 89046L, 
91384L, 89585L, 83771L, 83241L, 84151L, 6104L, 40574L, 48944L, 
81869L, 146953L, 135144L, 132819L, 134255L, 131648L, 141696L, 
122204L, 122752L, 120927L, 112159L, 102239L, 95998L, 97600L, 
99032L, 79662L, 76622L, 69585L, 73822L, 74488L, 75621L, 69098L, 
73761L, 76429L, 75664L, 77671L, 77090L, 77835L, 68888L, 69091L, 
73986L, 84497L, 91080L, 90245L, 82691L, 78239L, 83518L, 80689L, 
85564L, 89912L, 101674L, 103058L, 98647L, 111911L, 109854L, 139952L, 
138776L, 140779L, 129910L, 114445L, 114822L, 115894L, 121939L, 
124642L, 123978L, 120518L, 117401L, 118844L, 118196L, 117715L, 
117497L), price_purchase = c(130.76, 419.6, 251.74, 252.88, 64.02, 
272.59, 172.72, 88.81, 28.73, 1003.86, 346.47, 130.48, 29.86, 
280.11, 358.57, 385.83, 287.61, 22.95, 58.08, 854.08, 28.28, 
62.91, 994.86, 51.22, 9.01, 77.21, 244.15, 366.16, 366.8, 213.25, 
35.52, 566.3, 35.78, 1106.82, 64.35, 722.18, 131.66, 166.1, 823.9, 
138.23, 334.6, 328.19, 243.51, 488.8, 159.57, 106.8, 54.03, 27, 
308.63, 1022.42, 463.31, 144.66, 44.53, 25.48, 126.18, 365.52, 
133.92, 97.27, 12.84, 1002.55, 107.41, 132.31, 131.2, 789.57, 
230.2, 12.36, 229.86, 1386.91, 154.19, 18.19, 76.96, 882.49, 
191.55, 46.08, 24.17, 102.65, 326.62, 924.06, 923.73, 88.29, 
41.16, 128.42, 326.88, 137.96, 30.68, 108.88, 181.19, 241.34, 
128.32, 137.46, 1279.81, 643.23, 1275.16, 717.245, 159.33, 745.37, 
288.27, 177.26, 168.58, 66.85, 331.51, 437.31, 643.23, 9.3, 0.85, 
436.3, 105.51, 7.7, 79.44, 1321.37, 160.89, 107.21, 172.25, 514.79, 
141.06, 900.64, 153.22, 924.4, 176.34, 94.98, 162.6, 1326.25, 
39.9, 38.15, 2162.22, 180.95, 153.41, 720.48, 720.48, 15.42, 
140.28, 514.02, 720.47, 174.7, 197.69, 411.08, 741.07, 230.12, 
501.89, 109.34, 643.26, 23.17, 242.48, 1317.36, 69.76, 178.11, 
153.55, 32.18, 812.06, 302.2, 153.34, 172.03, 128.68, 939.54, 
108.04, 165.89, 56.63, 43.76, 171.17, 98.59, 21.95, 280.28, 181.47, 
730.01, 159.31, 60.75, 31.15, 1412.39, 7.14, 942.84, 321.06, 
165.51, 284.95, 169.42, 303.48, 224.3, 416.43, 385.85, 492.08, 
334.6, 1415.45, 123.53, 308.55, 60.49, 334.35, 771.96, 126.88, 
73.36, 203.84, 164.48, 143.89, 74.36, 23.17, 2.55, 7.84, 168, 
935.67, 208.24, 269.22, 14.32, 8.98, 128.94, 40.67, 150.04, 48.65, 
309.27, 37.3, 489.79, 82.11, 3.84, 563.44, 918.26, 470.8), purchase = c(19307, 
19469, 19255, 27041, 23494, 22171, 21378, 23072, 22748, 21993, 
26224, 25373, 29561, 28405, 26372, 31394, 28318, 25850, 24657, 
25098, 25167, 25385, 24731, 23999, 23929, 22653, 23403, 21112, 
20374, 20817, 20099, 22458, 21864, 22145, 26889, 24875, 25319, 
24863, 25714, 22768, 22878, 24931, 22725, 22548, 22124, 45185.5, 
68247, 185195, 28537, 24967, 24947, 25266, 24187, 22243, 23163, 
24827, 24226, 24443, 24305, 32107, 28178, 28345, 28548, 24358, 
24473, 25469, 27505, 27012, 25766, 26802, 27059, 25906, 26044, 
26712, 26559, 35077, 63796, 51899, 49578, 48212, 46405, 44255, 
44719, 46602, 44917, 44949, 44154, 43081, 45287, 49597, 50729, 
38233, 3574, 13975.5, 24377, 28938, 28427, 28875, 27722, 27510, 
26492, 27481, 26059, 25869, 27525, 26322, 27121, 29614, 35086, 
32884, 32548, 32619, 31698, 30089, 30398, 27579, 26662, 26880, 
27052, 26841, 27403, 27612, 33750, 32536, 32308, 28645, 27652, 
28276, 28533, 28426, 25379, 26027, 46480, 60013, 102117, 83216, 
76048, 72365, 87586, 63260, 36377, 31438, 31258, 29324, 28946, 
29017, 27884, 28063, 27809, 27499, 27490, 26316, 31358, 55087, 
46356, 45228, 44406, 43521, 45501, 40281, 41091, 41681, 39266, 
36268, 34754, 35341, 35943, 28852, 27810, 25186, 25501, 26232, 
25775, 23698, 25314, 25960, 26259, 27487, 26966, 25817, 21294, 
22704, 23997, 27250, 29639, 28900, 25449, 23845, 25050, 24045, 
25544, 26410, 30056, 31179, 29752, 33751, 34105, 41573, 43563, 
43421, 39800, 34089, 22, 29, 40618, 41499, 41579, 40945, 39870, 
41703, 40669, 40671, 41733), ctr = c(0.0157890561813006, 0.0166396305077271, 
0.0173986509381537, 0.0194731497951218, 0.0179954394804347, 0.01711863909483, 
0.0181582360570687, 0.0171927115779559, 0.0172358403646591, 0.0174638541971058, 
0.0178806664612045, 0.017462347179514, 0.0183790774089859, 0.0199881077619723, 
0.0174426987635606, 0.021089685240109, 0.0205569049800296, 0.0177842661874661, 
0.0173413941476575, 0.0169081718788632, 0.0182456430344012, 0.0182626162052032, 
0.0182543279386951, 0.0186259961442581, 0.0170104683085926, 0.0171132003490177, 
0.0171517774365777, 0.0170457664943143, 0.016903142521019, 0.0175382134561578, 
0.0164120092891695, 0.0157969704536582, 0.014264557168488, 0.0143332034531726, 
0.0152322825367764, 0.0147200846456646, 0.0152154800186776, 0.0140607309566817, 
0.0137719608789332, 0.0122855439272407, 0.0119334194687182, 0.0125752060979989, 
0.01158007808718, 0.0113191407332442, 0.00729059877222415, 0.00731911608538772, 
0.0106771470535411, 0.029937936916542, 0.0143512493034839, 0.0146854166936255, 
0.0149305898441825, 0.015325442746133, 0.015691446743994, 0.0144534643673336, 
0.0147711815606066, 0.0158382630541111, 0.0148728508159624, 0.015102040564144, 
0.0148955533969277, 0.0176392994824187, 0.0163240478169816, 0.0158230497930639, 
0.0166871934499785, 0.0150557839107457, 0.0159453688844757, 0.0158074236363467, 
0.0158454822084702, 0.0149292254566175, 0.0142730130593139, 0.0156929838274791, 
0.0156162350209032, 0.0153802494466767, 0.0150476029799385, 0.015555365325721, 
0.0143761174252573, 0.0154064275947974, 0.0208510166815324, 0.0176754346231314, 
0.0176296702464377, 0.01808584587117, 0.0184482114318881, 0.0179540460804964, 
0.0172054387638893, 0.0186435592467685, 0.0183226179107802, 0.0183442319676677, 
0.0186738733252132, 0.0197702609494553, 0.0204285359857455, 0.0189093019186096, 
0.0207614056972417, 0.0221922195760301, 0.00240617175649865, 
0.00788575626634226, 0.01309841408011, 0.0157695717780358, 0.0156402333683254, 
0.0162649757475833, 0.0155814665868539, 0.0165668899473124, 0.0162596037350689, 
0.0168350415867981, 0.0154154128099543, 0.0150464847912372, 0.0161870630522126, 
0.0156293605393382, 0.0166831626222356, 0.0159851624182969, 0.0181646017543342, 
0.0154736802975027, 0.0147489845006063, 0.0172093148404027, 0.0173801189598905, 
0.0179353887292393, 0.017586875624838, 0.0169123585500959, 0.0155822266067893, 
0.0149761651657073, 0.0167448758587691, 0.0161082597966258, 0.0167303551270177, 
0.0154917937591837, 0.015286011465188, 0.0136306070303869, 0.0152129210946259, 
0.0159440585908669, 0.0161367409642245, 0.0164079686231546, 0.016492577386447, 
0.0155465861608803, 0.0151072490270382, 0.0144004027929932, 0.0251766100192941, 
0.0300583807652007, 0.0394582941939502, 0.0346703430162482, 0.0370259651104479, 
0.0354306787130485, 0.0369234479028471, 0.0313956783546004, 0.0175071227813499, 
0.0153811379243536, 0.0149988963637585, 0.0159494386911496, 0.0151254119566314, 
0.0151138709885764, 0.0152175253675449, 0.015437458845637, 0.0147726989007463, 
0.163043027137275, 0.0264129334017437, 0.0201436139554002, 0.0169325780144314, 
0.0214876387664511, 0.0177445890793224, 0.0172606914733451, 0.017133563936406, 
0.0185813515317095, 0.0180607614170281, 0.0187505760492009, 0.0169511102933927, 
0.0178137558385877, 0.0184785698285323, 0.0201169476464591, 0.0220364679005246, 
0.0212945438945016, 0.021660499704709, 0.0203399246100257, 0.021042755155702, 
0.0207706911083365, 0.0191080416224264, 0.0188521002714409, 0.0176177277744931, 
0.0170654092407268, 0.0167173964870618, 0.0169957130997929, 0.0173290930652611, 
0.018723068602435, 0.0190819762151085, 0.0178334964691514, 0.0160768402598991, 
0.0172883539665594, 0.0176745227466401, 0.0176229174238593, 0.0192486537177652, 
0.0184480409967815, 0.016738809715337, 0.0152409794110955, 0.0164830717865742, 
0.0156835503722764, 0.0146390833265517, 0.014437303236394, 0.0152291157019601, 
0.0150381488303582, 0.0144744286877027, 0.0154780133881995, 0.0165875912852526, 
0.0167586910540363, 0.016434923542878, 0.016619416098569, 0.0156371489941345, 
0.0150586881991463, 9.20923636174885e-06, 1.20043248684906e-05, 
0.0164035785954663, 0.0163922122870294, 0.0158218503562475, 0.0150495685631071, 
0.0147135181693682, 0.0165419629891279, 0.015608161423137, 0.0152906026574993, 
0.0157815980810835)), row.names = c(NA, -213L), class = "data.frame")
````

Answer (score 0):

`as.ts()` converts a numeric vector to a `ts` object, but it does not convert from one time series class to another. For that you need the `tsbox` package. In your example, you can convert your data frame to a tsibble, and then to a ts object (although why you would want to do that, I have no idea).

```r
Oct_Apr |> 
  tsibble::as_tsibble(index = "date") |> 
  tsbox::ts_ts()
```

In general, `ts` objects are extremely limited, and with daily data, you would be better using `tsibble` objects and the functions provided in the `feasts` and `fable` packages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I try to create a forecasting with random forest, as shown in this example: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/09/time-series-forecasting-with-random-forest/. I will try to create it with the data as tsibble objects!